# Consider special charecter into .csv File

Tags: iphone, ios, csv

I am working on application, in it I have to consider all special characters.I am using  below code but in it I also want to consider "space and comma" but in it, when trigger space it make split at that place and make new fild for it..so friends is there any solutions to consider special characters.If you have any idea then please suggest me.Thanks

```
   arrCsv=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hello",@"Hi",@"traun  testdata",@"Hi,fine",nil];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains

(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/try.csv", documentsDirectory];


[[arrCsv componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "consider"? You want to split the string by space and other special chars?

Comment: @Terente Ionut Alexandru: I took it to mean that they want to be able to handle all "special" characters, e.g. non-alphanumeric.

Comment: hi first thanks for rply...I want to consider all string betweemn" "..means i have one string @"HI I am, Hello" this whole string i want to consider with 1 fild.but when there is trigger space or comma it make another fild for that

Comment: In array i have two string obj like..@"hello",@"Hi sinh,thanks"...I want to make csv split between them but it split in 4 fild..hello,hi,sinh,thanks..I want that whole string and want to split only between two object.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own CSV parsing routines in a simplistic fashion is both error-prone and needlessly time-consuming. I highly recommend you use Dave DeLong's excellent [CHCSV](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) library.

If you wanted to use this library, you could do something along the following lines to write two rows to a file:

```
NSArray *row1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Field One", @"Field Two", @"Field, three", nil];
NSArray *row2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Field' One", @"Field,, Two", @"Field\" three", nil];
NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:row1, row2, nil];

NSError *error = nil;
[rows writeToCSVFile:@"path/to/file.csv" atomically:YES error:&error];
if (error) {
    // do something with error
}
```

Comment: @sinh99: I added a quick snippet of example usage to my answer.